# Use type never with interface/class implementations in Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, interface

I'd like to use the typescript **never** type in order to be sure I've checked all the possible implementations of an interface. [Here is the code:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20MyInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass1%20implements%20MyInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass2%20implements%20MyInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(arg%3A%20MyInterface)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(arg%20instanceof%20MyClass1)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(arg%20instanceof%20MyClass2)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20assertNever(arg)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20assertNever(value%3A%20never)%3A%20never%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20throw%20Error(%60Unexpected%20value%20'%24%7Bvalue%7D'%60)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

```
interface MyInterface {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

class MyClass1 implements MyInterface {
    a: string;
    b: number;

    constructor() { }
}

class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {
    a: string;
    b: number;

    constructor() { }
}

function foo(arg: MyInterface) {
    if (arg instanceof MyClass1) {

    } else if (arg instanceof MyClass2) {

    } else {
        assertNever(arg);
    }
}

function assertNever(value: never): never {
  throw Error(`Unexpected value '${value}'`);
}
```

But I got the error: Argument of type 'MyInterface' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

Any ideas if there's a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `assertNever` approach to make sure all cases are handled (which is what I'm guessing you want to do). The problem is you need a union of all possibilities instead of using the interface. Typescript has no way of knowing what all the implementations of an interfaces will be so your type-guard will not narrow the type of the parameter.

This will work as you expect it to:

```
function foo(arg: MyClass1 | MyClass2) {
    if (arg instanceof MyClass1) {

    } else if (arg instanceof MyClass2) {

    } else {
        assertNever(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding never.

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

> The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself). Even any isn’t assignable to never.

You can't assign values to `never`
Since your type declaration is `assertNever(value: never)`  It will throw an error when assigning a variable to it when calling `assertNever(arg);`

Simply changing it to `assertNever(value: any): never` will fix the error. (Or a more specific type if you want)

Comment: Yes that's the point, I'd like to use the never type to assert that I've checked all the possible implementations of MyInterface.
If i check all the implementations, I can *never* end in the "else" block...